# Database design with Loan and LoanLines

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, check-constraints

I have not been able to come up with a viable solution for days.

I am developing a system to maintain items and lending out these items.

`Loan` contains `IEnumerable<LoanLine>` which each points at an `Item`:

[image: LoanSystem]

So far so good.
The tricky part comes to light when each item can't be lent out in the same period. And that period is defined by `LoanLine.PickedUp ?? Loan.DateFrom > LoanLine.Returned ?? Loan.DateTo`. This means that if `LoanLine.PickedUp` is null, then `Loan.DateFrom` should be used to compare, and if `LoanLine.Returned` is null, then `Loan.DateTo` should be used.
An item *can* be picked up and returned outside the loans boundaries. So these scenarioes can occur:

[image: Scenarioes which lines can occur in]

It should also be possible to "go back", ie. set `LoanLine.Returned` to null, in which case `Loan.DateTo` is used to compare again. The same goes with `LoanLine.PickedUp`.
It should also be possible to update both `Loan.DateFrom` and `Loan.DateTo`, with the berforementioned constraints still in effect. That means that if an update to `Loan` results in one of the lines, with either `DateTime` set to null, is overlapping, then the constraint shall throw an error.

This is the create-script:

```
create table loan
(
    id                  int             primary key identity(1, 1),
    datefrom            date            not null,
    dateto              date            not null,
    employee_id         int             references employee(id) not null,
    recipient_id        int             references employee(id) null,
    note                nvarchar(max)   not null,
    constraint c_loan_chkdates check (datefrom <= dateto)
);

create table loanlineitem
(
    id                  int             primary key identity(1, 1),
    loan_id             int             references loan(id) on delete cascade not null,
    item_id             int             references item(id) not null,
    pickedup            datetime        null,
    returned            datetime        null,
    constraint uq_loanlineitem unique (loan_id, item_id),
    constraint c_loanlineitem_chkdates check (returned is null or pickedup <= returned)
);
```

And this is the constraint:

```
create function checkLoanLineItem(@itemId int, @loanId int, @pickedup datetime, @returned datetime)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @result bit = 0;
    declare @from date = @pickedup;
    declare @to date = @returned;
    
    --If either @from or @to is null, fill the ones with null from loan-table
    if (isnull(@from, @to) is null)
    begin
        select  @from = isnull(@from, datefrom),
                @to = isnull(@to, dateadd(d, 1, dateto))
        from    loan
        where   id = @loanId;
    end

    if not exists (select top 1 lli.id from loanlineitem lli
        inner join loan l on lli.loan_id = l.id
        where l.id <> @loanId
        and lli.item_id = @itemId
        and ((isnull(lli.pickedup, l.datefrom) >= @from and isnull(lli.pickedup, l.datefrom) < @to)
            --When comparing datetime with date, the date's time is 00:00:00
            --so one day is added to account for this
            or (isnull(lli.returned, dateadd(d, 1, l.dateto)) >= @from and isnull(lli.returned, dateadd(d, 1, l.dateto)) < @to))
        )
    begin
        set @result = 1;
    end

    return @result;
end;

go;

alter table loanlineitem
add constraint c_loanlineitem_checkoverlap check (dbo.checkLoanLineItem(item_id, loan_id, pickedup, returned) = 1)

go;
```

I could make a similar constraint on `Loan`-table but then I would have similar code two places, which I would prefer to avoid, if possible.

---

So what I'm asking is; should I rethink my schema to accomplish this, or is it possible with some constraints which I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution, although it isn't the most elegant or DRY one.

First a view with occupations (thanks bbaird for the suggestion, which made it easier to figure out the logic):

```
create view vw_loanlineitem_occupations
as
select lli.id, loan_id, item_id, isnull(lli.pickedup, l.datefrom) as [from], isnull(lli.returned, dateadd(d, 1, l.dateto)) as [to] from loanlineitem lli inner join loan l on lli.loan_id = l.id
```

then a general check overlap udf:

```
create function udf_isOverlapping(@span1Start datetime, @span1End datetime, @span2Start datetime, @span2End datetime)
returns bit
as
begin
    return iif((@span1Start <= @span2End and @span1End >= @span2Start), 1, 0);
end
```

then a udf and constraint on loan:

```
create function udf_isLoanValid(@loanId int, @dateFrom date, @dateTo date)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @result bit = 0;

    --When type 'date' is compared to 'datetime' the time-part is 00:00:00, so add one day
    set @dateTo = dateadd(d, 1, @dateTo)

    if not exists (
        select top 1 lli.id from loanlineitem lli
        inner join loan l on lli.loan_id = l.id
        --Only check items that are in this loan
        where lli.item_id in (select item_id from loanlineitem where loan_id = @loanId)
        --Check if this span is overlapping with other lines/loans
        --When type 'date' is compared to 'datetime' the time-part is 00:00:00, so add one day
        and (dbo.udf_isOverlapping(
                @dateFrom,
                @dateTo,
                isnull(lli.pickedup, iif(l.id = @loanId, @dateFrom, l.datefrom)),
                isnull(lli.returned, iif(l.id = @loanId, @dateTo, dateadd(d, 1, l.dateto)))
                ) = 1
            )
        )
    begin
        set @result = 1
    end

    return @result;
end;

go;

alter table loan
add constraint c_loan_datecheck check (dbo.udf_isLoanValid(id, dateFrom, dateTo) = 1);
```

and a separate constraint on loanlineitem, which unfortunately repeats some of the code from loan's constraint:

```
create function udf_isLineValid(@itemId int, @loanId int, @pickedup datetime, @returned datetime)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @result bit = 0;
    declare @from date = @pickedup;
    declare @to date = @returned;
    
    --If either @from or @to is null, fill the ones with null from loan-table
    if (@from is null or @to is null)
    begin
        select  @from = isnull(@from, datefrom),
                @to = isnull(@to, dateadd(d, 1, dateto))
        from    loan
        where   id = @loanId;
    end

    --If no lines with overlap exists, this line is valid, so set result to 1
    if not exists (
        select top 1 id from vw_loanlineitem_occupations
        where item_id = @itemId
        and loan_id <> @loanId
        and dbo.udf_isOverlapping(@from, @to, [from], [to]) = 1
        )
    begin
        set @result = 1;
    end

    return @result;
end;

go;

alter table loanlineitem
add constraint c_loanlineitem_checkoverlap check (dbo.udf_isLineValid(item_id, loan_id, pickedup, returned) = 1)
```

It works, which is the most important part. I am not sure about how performance is, but data integrity is more important.

Answer (score 1):

For this we will need two things:

1. A way to track the status of an item with respect to a loan
2. Only allow one active loan at a point in time

The first item can be addressed through the data model (see below) but the second will require any changes to the database MUST occur through stored procedures and those stored procedures will have to contain logic to keep the database in a consistent state.  Otherwise you'll have a real mess on your hands (or rely on triggers, which is another headache).

We'll track the physical state of the item through an item status based on a timestamp, and, if desired, reservations through another mechanism based on a future date.

[image: Logical data model]

This query will return the current status and loan of all items, as well as the next reservation.  From this you can also determine which items are past due.

```
SELECT
  Item.ItemId
 ,ItemStatus.UpdateDtm
 ,ItemStatus.StatusCd
 ,ItemStatus.LoanNumber
 ,Loan.StartDt
 ,Loan.EndDt
 ,Reservation.StartDt
 ,Reservation.EndDt
FROM
  Item Item
LEFT JOIN
  LoanItemStatus ItemStatus
    ON ItemStatus.ItemId = Item.ItemId
        AND ItemStatus.UpdateDtm =
              (
                SELECT
                  MAX(UpdateDtm)
                FROM
                  LoanItemStatus
                WHERE
                  ItemId = Item.ItemId
              )
LEFT JOIN
  Loan Loan
    ON Loan.LoanNumber = ItemStatus.LoanNumber
LEFT JOIN
  ItemReservation Reservation
    ON Reservation.ItemId = Item.ItemId
        AND Reservation.StartDt =
              (
                SELECT
                  MIN(StartDt)
                FROM
                  ItemReservation
                WHERE
                  ItemId = Item.ItemId
                    AND StartDt >= GetDate()
              )
```

It will probably make sense to harden this logic into a view.

To see if an item is reserved during a given timeframe:

```
SELECT
  Item.ItemId
 ,CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(PriorReservation.EndDt,GETDATE()) <= @ReservationStartDt AND @ReservationEndDt <= COALESCE(NextReservation.StartDt,'9999-12-31') THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END AS ReservationAvailableInd
FROM
  Item Item
LEFT JOIN
  ItemReservation PriorReservation
    ON PriorReservation.ItemId = Item.ItemId
        AND PriorReservation.StartDt =
              (
                SELECT
                  MAX(StartDt)
                FROM
                  ItemReservation
                WHERE
                  ItemId = Item.ItemId
                    AND StartDt <= @ReservationStartDt
              )
LEFT JOIN
  ItemReservation NextReservation
    ON NextReservation.ItemId = Item.ItemId
        AND NextReservation.StartDt =
              (
                SELECT
                  MIN(StartDt)
                FROM
                  ItemReservation
                WHERE
                  ItemId = Item.ItemId
                    AND StartDt > @ReservationStartDt
              )
```

So you'll need to roll all of this into your stored procedures so:

1. When an item is loaned, it is available for the time period specified
2. When the loan date range is changed it does not conflict with the existing items or future reservations
3. When new reservations are made they do not conflict with existing <s>procedures</s> reservations
4. State transitions make sense (Not loaned/Returned -> Awaiting pickup -> Picked Up -> Returned/Lost)
5. You cannot delete loans with items that have been picked up or items that have been picked up

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I have also thought about stored procedures, but then there is still a risk of the database going "out of sync" if I for some reason would make changes directly with an update/insert-statement. I would prefer that constraints maintain that the database will always be in a valid state, no matter how I attempt to break it.

Comment: I came up with a solution, which works although it isn't the most elegant one.

Comment: You can lock all insert/update/delete to a single role that is not available outside of administrators.  Then you can use EXECUTE AS within each stored procedure to perform the required action without granting direct insert/update/delete access.